# Cannot enable Coherence mode in parallels 16

Tags: macos, ubuntu, parallels

I found some problem while I'm using parallels on my mac.
The environment is like below.

vmware : Parallels Desktop 16
virtual os : Ubuntu 20.10
Problem : Cannot Enter Coherence Mode (option menu disabled)

[Parallels Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiw2m.png)

Is there any other set-up to enable Coherence?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

have to resize screen smaller not full screen.